# Finding lost jsfiddles

Tags: jsfiddle

I am not sure this would be the best place to ask this so I apologize if I am in the wrong place.

So I started to make a temp page for my portfolio to inform people that a new redesign is taking place. I made a really nice temp page and had everything finalize except a little bit of content.

I saved the fiddle, named the fiddle, and even ended up on number 9 or 10 revision for the fiddle. I had this fiddle saved and ready to go but for some reason when I got home it was no where in my dashboard. I even checked public fiddles to see if it was in there but, sadly, it was not.

I then started to dig through any search engine I knew to try and find it and that was of little help. :/

So far I have not heard anything back from support@jsfiddle.net and decided I would try and find an answer on here.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated and really would rather not have to start over again. :/

Has anyone ran into this problem before, is there a way to search through peoples fiddles, or any search functionality at all?

Comment: You can check your browser history or perhaps get a response from the support at jsfiddle but I can't think of any other options

Comment: @Zeaklous Sadly I ended up just remaking the entire thing since the support was of little help. I cleared my history before I noticed it wasn't saved in there. :[ It was a sad day for me but I also learned to make sure it is in there before clearing my history ha.

Answer (score 2):

As @zach-saucier pointed out, the best solution is to access your browser history. I just thought I lost a very important Fiddle, because it didn't show up under Profile -> "All your fiddles".

But in my browser history (CTRL + H on most browsers), I found the URL to my fiddle. It was still there, and it says I'm the author, but it just doesn't show in my profile.